# List does not show correct entries

Tags: unity-game-engine, collections

I am trying to build a tile based world using the following world manager class:

```
 List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();
 for (int y = 0; y <= worldHeight-1; y++) {          
  for (int x = 0; x <= worldWidth-1; x++) {
   Tile tileToInstantiate = (Tile) Resources.Load("Prefabs/Tile", typeof(Tile));
   Instantiate(tileToInstantiate, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity, world);
   tiles.Add(tileToInstantiate);
  }
 }
 foreach (Tile aTile in tiles) {
   Debug.Log("D2: " + aTile.GetTerrainType());
 }
```

The Tile class is defined as follows:

```
private void Awake() {
int random = (int)Random.Range(0, 100);
if (random <= GameManager.instance.worldManager.amountOfWater){
  terrainType = TerrainType.Water; } else {
  terrainType = TerrainType.Land;}
  Debug.Log("D1: " + GetTerrainType());            
  spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); 
  switch (terrainType) {            {
    case TerrainType.Land:
      spriteRenderer.sprite = GameManager.instance.tileSprites[0];
      break;
    case TerrainType.Water:
    spriteRenderer.sprite = GameManager.instance.tileSprites[1];
    break;
```

However when I run the code, the following problems occurs: the tiles show the correct sprites and terrain types in the first debug statement. But in the second debug statement, the entries are not the same than in the first.
Where is the error?

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a prefab of your Tile to the list instead of the created instance. As such it's using the default value of the prefab instead (which I assume is Land).

I can't test this right now but I believe it should look more like.

```
Tile t = Instantiate(tileToInstantiate, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity, world);
tiles.Add(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said, you generate the tiles correctly. But you did not add the instance to list.

```
void Start () {
    List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        Tile tileToInstantiate = (Tile)Resources.Load("Prefabs/TilePrefab", typeof(Tile));
        Tile tileInstance = Instantiate(tileToInstantiate, tileParent.transform);
        tiles.Add(tileInstance);
    }
    foreach (Tile aTile in tiles)
    {
        Debug.Log("D2: " + aTile.type);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the result does not change when I change the code

Comment: But it must have to do with the loading of the prefab. I created a public variable to attach the prefab from editor and then everything works fine.